# How to create links within same jsp page

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have one jspfile named media.jsp which should have links such as:

`Audio
Video
Movies`

After clicking on audio i want data related to audio in that same page like this:

`Audio--> abc.mp3
          xyz.mp3
Video
Movies` 
How can this be done. I searched a lot but not getting any code related to same page. Can anyone help me out n this

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: after clicking on audio i want to show the list of all audio files but not in different jsp file. It should appear the way i showed above. Can u help me??